# How to show CiviCRM menu for non admin role using WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Using WP4.1.1 and Civi4.5.8

How do we display a menu for a non Admin WP role?   We created a new role in WP for CiviUsers and would like to display the top Civi menu like Admins get.
THANKS.

Comment: Could you clarify which menu you mean? Is it the regular civi menu with 'Search', 'Contacts' etc.?

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding correctly you wanting other roles to access CiviCRM menu, which is linked to the WordPress Access Control and giving that role CiviCRM: access CiviCRM. You would then have to give them the access to whatever other features are needed. These settings are in Administer > User and Permissions > Permissions (Access Control) and select WordPress Access Control.

Comment: That is already set.  We have a WP Role called CiviYHFH and the CiviCRM:access CiviCRM is checked.  When I log in the CiviMenu at the top does not appear.   I will have to check deeper....

Comment: Clearing cache maybe?

Comment: After digging deeper I found that the menus are being blocked by our main developer for security reasons!  Only Admins had access.